Make a list in python searchable like a dictionaries
At some point i have the following output iterating over a json file:
**ID:** 3979
**Title:**  Env: AppFamily PROD | Metric: Swap Memory Usage | Threshold >80% | Interval: 1min | Pending: 2min | Notification: teams/email
**Data:** [{'refId': 'A', 'queryType': '', 'relativeTimeRange': {'from': 60, 'to': 0}, 'datasourceUid': '000000001', 'model': {'editorMode': 'code', 'expr': '(1- mem_swap_free{env="prd", application=~"AllKindsofApps"} / mem_swap_total{env="prd", application=~"AllKindsofApps"})*100', 'instant': True, 'intervalMs': 1000, 'legendFormat': '__auto', 'maxDataPoints': 43200, 'range': False, 'refId': 'A'}}, {'refId': 'C', 'queryType': '', 'relativeTimeRange': {'from': 60, 'to': 0}, 'datasourceUid': '__expr__', 'model': {'conditions': [{'evaluator': {'params': [80], 'type': 'gt'}, 'operator': {'type': 'and'}, 'query': {'params': ['C']}, 'reducer': {'params': [], 'type': 'last'}, 'type': 'query'}], 'datasource': {'type': '__expr__', 'uid': '__expr__'}, 'expression': 'A', 'intervalMs': 1000, 'maxDataPoints': 43200, 'refId': 'C', 'type': 'threshold'}}]

I want to be able to extract the following from Data

expr
conditions

So that i end up with
expr: '(1- mem_swap_free{env="prd", application=~"AllKindsofApps"} / mem_swap_total{env="prd", application=~"AllKindsofApps"})*100'

and
'model': {'conditions': [{'evaluator': {'params': [80], 'type': 'gt'}, 'operator': {'type': 'and'}, 'query': {'params': ['C']}

I have tried the following to get the requested data:
-- convert the list to dict
-- convert the list to string and the try json.loads
-- trying to build a dict by going over the list
-- a lot of other ways trying to get some reasonable output
I want to understand with some help how to get the requested data available
Thank you in advance

Make a [mcve].  We don't need to see how to get jdata, just show us jdata, how you process it, what you get, and what you want.

@MarkTolonen thank you, i have edited the question to make it minimal reproducible example.

I may be misunderstanding what your after, but this sounds like a simple matter of looking into the list of dictionary objects provided by Data (which you seem to have already)
# this is your list of data dicts
data = [
    {'refId': 'A', 'queryType': '', 'relativeTimeRange': {'from': 60, 'to': 0}, 'datasourceUid': '000000001', 'model': {'editorMode': 'code', 'expr': '(1- mem_swap_free{env="prd", application=~"AllKindsofApps"} / mem_swap_total{env="prd", application=~"AllKindsofApps"})*100', 'instant': True, 'intervalMs': 1000, 'legendFormat': '__auto', 'maxDataPoints': 43200, 'range': False, 'refId': 'A'}},
    {'refId': 'C', 'queryType': '', 'relativeTimeRange': {'from': 60, 'to': 0}, 'datasourceUid': '__expr__', 'model': {'conditions': [{'evaluator': {'params': [80], 'type': 'gt'}, 'operator': {'type': 'and'}, 'query': {'params': ['C']}, 'reducer': {'params': [], 'type': 'last'}, 'type': 'query'}], 'datasource': {'type': '__expr__', 'uid': '__expr__'}, 'expression': 'A', 'intervalMs': 1000, 'maxDataPoints': 43200, 'refId': 'C', 'type': 'threshold'}}
]

# let's iterate over the data
for item in data:
    try:  
        # if the list item in question has a key 'model' which is a dictionary,
        # try to get the 'expr' value from that dictionary
        print(item['model']['expr'])
    except KeyError:
        # if 'model' exists but has no 'expr' key, just print the model dict instead
        print(item['model'])

This is a pretty naïve example, but should get you started. The gist is that Data is just a list of dictionaries, so you can iterate over it and pull items from those dictionaries just like usual.
The code above prints these two lines:
(1- mem_swap_free{env="prd", application=~"AllKindsofApps"} / mem_swap_total{env="prd", application=~"AllKindsofApps"})*100
{'conditions': [{'evaluator': {'params': [80], 'type': 'gt'}, 'operator': {'type': 'and'}, 'query': {'params': ['C']}, 'reducer': {'params': [], 'type': 'last'}, 'type': 'query'}], 'datasource': {'type': '__expr__', 'uid': '__expr__'}, 'expression': 'A', 'intervalMs': 1000, 'maxDataPoints': 43200, 'refId': 'C', 'type': 'threshold'}

